# CSS3 animation not playing / happening on <main> element

Tags: css

I am trying to get the `<main>` element to slide up from the bottom of the viewport of page load.

I am using an already built animation that works, but when I apply it to the  element, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a JSFiddle that recreates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5hshn/

There isn't any weird or conflicting CSS applied to the main element, as seen in the JSFiddle the CSS, for styling not animation, that is being applied to the `<main>` is as follows:

```
main, [role="main"], #main{
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;
    display:block;
}
```

#### Update:

External resource wasn't loading in JSFiddle, here is a version with the animation CSS( http://jsfiddle.net/5hshn/2/ ). Now, the JS Fiddle is working. But it is still not working in my implementation. Here is a link to my implementation: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/animate/new.html

Comment: You don't have any `@keyframes` defined, nor any `animation` CSS rule. How exactly do you expect it to work?

Comment: I think the OP forgot to include the animation, please update the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hshn/1/)

Comment: @Kolink I do, it is included as an external resource in the JsFiddle.

Comment: @Adrift it is an external resource in the JSFiddle

Comment: Getting a 404 when trying to view it, please update, thank you!

Comment: @Adrift Will do, sorry about that.

Comment: @Adrift Updated the js fiddle and the question. Now, Js Fiddle is working, but my implementation of same code is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation is fine. However your animate.css file containing the keyframes and .animate class is not loading.

Change in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylsheet" href="animate.css" type="text/css" />
to
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
```

or move the contents of animate.css to your new.html file style element and it should work.

Edit: you made a typo. Its `stylesheet` not `stylsheet`

Comment: Does changing it from a self-closing tag to an open tag really fix it? Any idea why? Is the file corrupt or wrong or something?

Comment: You can check your document.styleSheets and see that your style is not registered. Also if you check out the Network panel you will see that there is no request made for animate.css. Is eighter that or you are serving it with a different mimetype.

Comment: You actually made a typo. Its stylesheet not stylsheet. its not about the self closing tag.